# Contenteditable with ng-model doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, contenteditable, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to store the value of a `contenteditable` to my JS code. But I can't find out why `ng-model` doesn't work in this case.

```
<div ng-app="Demo" ng-controller="main">
    <input ng-model="inputValue"></input>
    <div>{{inputValue}}</div> // Works fine with an input
    <hr/>
    <div contenteditable="true" ng-model="contentValue"></div>
    <div>{{contentValue}}</div> // Doesn't work with a contenteditable
</div>
```

Is there a workaround to do that ?

See : [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gatdk6g9/)

**Note:** I'm creating a Text editor, so the user should see the result, while I'm storing the HTML behind it. (ie. user see: "This is an **example** !", while I store: `This is an <b>example</b> !`)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

contenteditable tag will not work directly with angular's ng-model because the way contenteditable rerender the dom element on every change.

You have to wrap it with a custom directive for that:

## JS:

```
angular.module('customControl', ['ngSanitize']).
directive('contenteditable', ['$sce', function($sce) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
    require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      if (!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

      // Specify how UI should be updated
      ngModel.$render = function() {
        element.html($sce.getTrustedHtml(ngModel.$viewValue || ''));
      };

      // Listen for change events to enable binding
      element.on('blur keyup change', function() {
        scope.$evalAsync(read);
      });
      read(); // initialize

      // Write data to the model
      function read() {
        var html = element.html();
        // When we clear the content editable the browser leaves a <br> behind
        // If strip-br attribute is provided then we strip this out
        if ( attrs.stripBr && html == '<br>' ) {
          html = '';
        }
        ngModel.$setViewValue(html);
      }
    }
  };
}]);
```

## HTML

```
<form name="myForm">
 <div contenteditable
      name="myWidget" ng-model="userContent"
      strip-br="true"
      required>Change me!</div>
  <span ng-show="myForm.myWidget.$error.required">Required!</span>
 <hr>
 <textarea ng-model="userContent"></textarea>
</form>
```

Source it from the [original docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#custom-control-example)

Comment: I already saw this code in the doc, but didn't understand its use correctly, your few lines made me understand. =)

Comment: It doesn't render `ng-model` value. Let's say instead of static text "Change me!" I have a variable it shows variable as is.

Comment: @Ben Diamant: As soon as start editing the contenteditable div, on every keystroke my cursor goes to the start of the div. Have to click at the desired location to edit again.

Comment: this answers code is similar as that of angular [docs example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#example)

Comment: using AngularJS v1.6.7 and ngSanitizeis throwing an $injector:modulerr
Module Error

Answer (score 8):

Just move the read function call into $render

```
angular.module('customControl', ['ngSanitize']).
directive('contenteditable', ['$sce', function($sce) {
  return {
  restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
  require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
  link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      if (!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

    // Specify how UI should be updated
      ngModel.$render = function() {
        element.html($sce.getTrustedHtml(ngModel.$viewValue || ''));
        read(); // initialize
      };

      // Listen for change events to enable binding
      element.on('blur keyup change', function() {
        scope.$evalAsync(read);
      });

      // Write data to the model
      function read() {
        var html = element.html();
        // When we clear the content editable the browser leaves a <br> behind
        // If strip-br attribute is provided then we strip this out
        if ( attrs.stripBr && html == '<br>' ) {
          html = '';
        }
        ngModel.$setViewValue(html);
      }
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: Why is this wrong in the original AngularJS example?

Comment: It works because you have to set the viewValue after rendering or the view won't reflect changes to the model, and moving the read function call into $render achieves just that

Comment: I just wonder why they didn't do it this way in their example, because this makes much more sense

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the other answers worked for me. I needed the model's initial value to be rendered when the control was initialized. Instead of calling `read()`, I used this code inside the `link` function:

```
ngModel.$modelValue = scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel);
ngModel.$setViewValue(ngModel.$modelValue);
ngModel.$render()
```