# AngularJS in line edit

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a small piece of code, which I would like to extend with in line editting possibilities:

HTML:

```
<h1>Schedule <label ng-click="modifyText(index)">{{th.schedules[index].label}} </label>
</h1>
```

JS:

```
$scope.modifyText = function(index) {
            this.th.schedules[index].label = 'modifiedtext';    
        };
```

Hence I would like to be able to click {{th.schedules[index].label}}, modify it inline to the string: "modifiedtext", and save it.

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: You should have a look at `ngModel` which is a fundamental directive of AngularJS that is part of what you are looking for.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to edit a label inline, you would probably have to use the `contentEditable` attribute since it isn't directly an editable element. If you give it an `ng-model` changing that data could be easier but you will still have to make a UI for actually editing it.

Instead I made an example using a text input and some simple styling to make it seem as though it isn't a text input when it isn't focused

http://jsfiddle.net/yrakrj48/

```
//-- HTML
<body ng-app="TestApp">
    <div ng-controller="TestController">
        <input ng-class="editing ? 'hasBorder' : 'noBorder'" type="text" ng-model="myLabel" ng-focus="editing = true" />
        <button ng-if="editing" ng-click="saveEdit()">done</button>
    </div>
</body>

//-- JS
var app = angular.module('TestApp',[]);

app.controller('TestController', function($scope) {
  $scope.myLabel = 'this is a label';

    $scope.saveEdit = function() {
        $scope.editing = false;
    };
});

//-- CSS
.hasBorder {
    border:1px solid #666;
}

.noBorder {
    border:none;
}
```

You should look into directives because creating one would be easy and I am sure one already exists somewhere out on github

Comment: Thanks, Ronnie! This is almost what I'm looking for. Could it be done without the 'done' button?

Comment: Certainly, you could use `ng-blur`. Really, as soon as you start typing on the field, the model is being updated. I am not sure what the saving part of your question entails, but here is an example with `ng-blur`: http://jsfiddle.net/yrakrj48/1/

Comment: The saving part has to do with the variable I created: 'th.schedules[index].label'. I would like to update that string with the content typed in the textfield.

Comment: I would like to add something like ng-click="modifyText(variable); and have this modifyText in my controller, updating th.schedules[index].label

Answer (score 0):

I think you use. **contenteditable=true**

```
<div contenteditable=true>
 I am Editable
</div>
```

Comment: I think in order for that to work, you need to do a little more work than that. The model won't be updated this way, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28583740/736967