# Angular contenteditable change event not fired

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, angularjs-scope, contenteditable

I have an issue to apply a direct change to my controller scope on `execCommand`.

The `change` event is not fired in the contenteditable directive found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28583740/1204267) and I have to blur the `div` to apply the changes. Is it a bug or there is something to do in addition ?

Here my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thomasleduc/96g4ks59/3/) for testing.

=== EDIT ===

The bold execCommand is working on dom but it doesn't update directly the controller scope unless an event is trigger like keyup on the field or blur.

[image: Real time field is not update]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `change` event does not fire on all changes to the value of the DOM element. The solution is to use the `input` event.

```
  element.on('input', function() {
      scope.$evalAsync(read);
  });
```

---

> ### change
>
> Unlike the [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event, the change event is not necessarily fired for each change to an element's value.

--[Mozilla Developer Network -- Events -- Change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)

---

> ### input
>
> The DOM input event is fired synchronously when the value of an [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) or [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) element is changed. **Additionally, it fires on [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable) editors when its contents are changed.** In this case, the event target is the editing host element. If there are two or more elements which have contenteditable as true, "editing host" is the nearest ancestor element whose parent isn't editable.

--[Mozilla Developer Network -- Events -- Input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input)

Comment: Thx a lot, it's the perfect answer ! ;) The updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thomasleduc/t0b07ote/)