# Binding raw object output to a form representation

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to update models from a JSON representation of an object to a form. Here's a [link to an example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJJXxY)

To recreate my issue,

1. Change the data in the form (see that the JSON changes).
2. Change the JSON (See that the form doesn't change).

Here's my code:

JS

```
var ppl = {
  createdby: "foo",
  dateCreated: "bar",
}
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller("Ctrl_List", function($scope) {
  $scope.people = ppl
  $scope.print = JSON.stringify($scope.ppl)
})
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="Ctrl_List">

    <!-- FORM -->
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="(key,val) in people track by $index">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <label for="{{key}}">{{key}}</label>
        <input class=form-control" id="{{key}}" ng-model="people[key]">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- JSON -->
    <div class="editable" contenteditable="true" ng-model="people">{{people}}</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

> **When a user changes the JSON, the form should update in real-time.**

---

Here's some things I have tried:

- Change the JSON display element from `div` to `input` but it prints `[Object][Object]`
- Also `<input ng-model="JSON.stringify(people)">` but I get an "unbindable element" error.
- Also tried adding a new model: `$scope.print = JSON.stringify(people)` but it shows nothing in the raw output.

Is it even possible to update a live object or am I gonna have to do some sort of event that triggers the form to change?

PS: Angular 1.5.8

Comment: Works for me :https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ryyqeE?editors=0001

Comment: Thanks, but I'm wondering if I can do it without a triggered event (see the 2nd to last line). Edit: I updated my question to clarify this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several reasons why this doesn't work:

1. ng-model on a `div` doesn't do anything
2. even if it did, it would save a string to `people`, and your form would thus not work anymore.

You should use a textarea to make it work, and bind it to another variable, of type string. Using ng-change on the textarea, and on the inputs of the form, allows populating the `people` object by parsing the JSON string, and vice-verse, populating the JSON string from the `people` object.

See https://codepen.io/anon/pen/peexPG for a demo.

Comment: OK, so it's not possible to do this without a triggered event - that's what I thought. Thanks, your demo worked.

Answer (score 1):

Refering to [Contenteditable with ng-model doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28583651/contenteditable-with-ng-model-doesnt-work),

> contenteditable tag will not work directly with angular's ng-model because the way contenteditable rerender the dom element on every change.