# Update the array as we edit the table column value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to `angularjs`. I have a table in my html file which is like

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered report-table" fixed-header>
                <thead class="text-center text-info">
                <th class="text-center">A</th>
                <th class="text-center">B</th>
                <th class="text-center">C</th>
                <th class="text-center">D</th>
                </thead>
                <tr ng-repeat="report in reports.data">
                  <td class="text-center">{{ report.attributes.a }}</td>
                  <td class="td-report-field">{{ report.attributes.b }}</td>
                  <td contenteditable = "true"><input type="checkbox" ng-if="report.attributes.c.length > 0 && showcheckbox" ng-bind="report.attributes.c" ng-click="getcheckedData(report.attributes.c)">{{ report.attributes.c }}</td>
                  <td class="text-center">{{ report.attributes.score }}</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
```

In my controller -

```
$scope.loadReports = function () {
                    $scope.loadingReports = true;
                    if($scope.documentType === "jobDescription"){
                        $scope.showcheckbox = false;
                        $scope.showSendButton = false;
                    }
                    uploadService.loadReports(uploadService.currentFileName, $scope.documentType)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            $scope.checkCandidateInfo();
                            $scope.reports = response;
                            $scope.loadingReports = false;
                        },
                        function (error) {
                            $scope.loadingReports = false;
                            $scope.errorMessage = error.status + " : " + error.statusText;
                            if (error.status === 401) {
                                loginService.authenticationError();
                            }
                        });
                };
```

My service -

```
loadReports : function(fileName, docType) {
                    var url = 'rez' + '/reports/' + docType + '/' + fileName;
                    var config = {};
                    config.headers = {
                        "X-AUTH-TOKEN": loginService.getAuthToken()
                    };
                    return $http.get(url, config)
                      .then(function(response){
                          return response.data;
                      },
                      function(error){
                          $log.error(error);
                          return $q.reject(error);
                      });
                },

$scope.getcheckedData = function(SelectedVal) {     
                    if($.inArray(SelectedVal , messages) === -1) {
                          messages.push(SelectedVal);
                    } else {
                          var index = messages.indexOf(SelectedVal);
                          messages.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                        if(messages.length > 0) {
                            $scope.sendButtondisable = false;
                        }else {
                            $scope.sendButtondisable = true;
                        }  
                        return messages;      
                };
```

loadReports calling from -

```
$scope.tabSelected = function (selectedTab) {
                    if (selectedTab.id === "report-score") {
                        $scope.showSaveButton = false;
                        $scope.loadReports();
                    }
                };
```

So, Here I made third field as a editable.I am able to edit it but when I send that value that time it is not taking the edited value, It is taking the previous value which was in that array. So, How can solve this issue ?

Comment: share the code of function(s) being called

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28583651/contenteditable-with-ng-model-doesnt-work

Comment: @tanmayupdated the code

Comment: where is the code for function getcheckedData? also where did you called the loadReports function in your scope?

Comment: @Pengyyupdated the question

Comment: I have take some more time to understand your question. And i think that you should remove those code blocks which has nothing related to your problem such as the service logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `ng-model="reports"` to your `contenteditable` td, or something like that (i don't know, what are you editing). You just need to bind it to the right variable of scope.

Comment: I am  making the table cells directly editable using the HTML contenteditable attribute, ng-model won't work automatically as by default it's only for form element.