# how to make 2 ways data-binding for td in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I need to use this editable column to display a "test" variable :

```
<td contentEditable="true" ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="test">{{test}}</td>
```

My td element displays the initial value of "test", but when I edit the td (using my keyboard), "test" does not change.

I have tested the same thing using input, and it works :

```
<input id="myinput" name="myinput" type="text" [(ngModel)]="test">
```

So what is the problem ?

Comment: How are you editing this exactly? All that is is a column/cell without input. The text is directly in the cell as content.

Comment: contentEditable="true" is used to make a column/cell editable

Comment: its not an exact duplicate as this is angular1 but still relevant.: [Contenteditable with ng-model doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28583651/1260204)

Comment: how many rows and cols are there

Comment: how to use `directive` in angular 2 ?

Comment: there are 2 rows and 5 cols

Comment: yes thanks lexith, I tried `[textContent]="test" (input)="test=$event.target.textContent" ` in place of [(ngModel)]  and it works, I also omitted this `ngDefaultControl `.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried this :

```
<td contentEditable="true" [textContent]="test" (input)="test=$event.target.textContent">{{test}}</td>
```

And it works.