# Angularjs: Local storage contenteditable not saving

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Local storage ceases to work when I try to extend it to include contentEditable. Local storage ceases to work when I try to extend it to include contentEditable. The following is the link to the CodePen: https://codepen.io/zanderbush/pen/WNwWbWe. Any help is appreciated.

Alone, this works.

```
var app = angular.module('TodoApp', ["LocalStorageModule"]);

app.controller('TodoController', function($scope, localStorageService) {
  
  if (!localStorageService.get("taskListActive")) {
    $scope.tasksActive = [
      {
        text: "Do me next",
        priority: 1,
        complete: false
      },
      {
        text: "I'm not important",
        priority: 0,
        complete: false
      }
    ];
    
  } else {
    $scope.tasksActive = localStorageService.get("taskListActive");
  }
  
  if (!localStorageService.get("taskListComplete")) {
    $scope.tasksComplete = [
      {
        text: "I'm already done",
        priority: 0,
        complete: true
      }
    ];
  } else {
    $scope.tasksComplete = localStorageService.get("taskListComplete");
  }
  
  $scope.totalTasks = function() {
    console.log($scope.tasksComplete.length)
    return $scope.tasksActive.length + $scope.tasksComplete.length;
  }
  
  $scope.totalRemaining = function() {
    return $scope.tasksActive.length;
  };
  
  $scope.totalComplete = function() {
    return $scope.tasksActive.length;
  };
  
  $scope.todoAdd = function() {
    if ($scope.taskInput.name) {
      $scope.tasksActive.unshift({ text:$scope.taskInput.name, priority:$scope.taskInput.priority || 0, complete:false});
      $scope.taskInput.name = '';
      $scope.taskInput.priority = 0;
    }
  };
  
  $scope.togglePriority = function(task) {
    if( task.priority === 0 ) {
      task.priority = 1;
      console.log('a')
    } else {
      task.priority = 0;
    }
  };
  
  $scope.completeTask = function(task) {
    //var task = $scope.tasksActive[index];
    task.complete = true;
    task.priority = 0;
    $scope.tasksActive.splice($scope.tasksActive.indexOf(task), 1);
    $scope.tasksComplete.unshift(task);
  };
  
  $scope.uncompleteTask = function(task) {
    task.complete = false;
    $scope.tasksComplete.splice($scope.tasksComplete.indexOf(task), 1);
    $scope.tasksActive.unshift(task);
  };
  
  $scope.deleteTask = function(task,list) {
    if( list == "active" ) {
      $scope.tasksActive.splice($scope.tasksActive.indexOf(task), 1);
    } else {
      $scope.tasksComplete.splice($scope.tasksComplete.indexOf(task), 1);
    }
    
  };
   
  $scope.clearCompleted = function () {
      var deleteArr= [];
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tasksComplete.length; i++) deleteArr.push(i);
      for (var i = 0; i < deleteArr.length; i++) {
        var task = i;
        $scope.tasksComplete.splice($scope.tasksComplete.indexOf(task) - 1, 1);
      }
  };

  $scope.$watch("tasksActive",function  (newVal,oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== null && angular.isDefined(newVal) && newVal!==oldVal) {
            localStorageService.add("taskListActive",angular.toJson(newVal));
        }
    },true);
  
  $scope.$watch("tasksComplete",function  (newVal,oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== null && angular.isDefined(newVal) && newVal!==oldVal) {
            localStorageService.add("taskListComplete",angular.toJson(newVal));
        }
    },true);
  
});
```

However, when I add the following code to accomodate for contentEditable, neither work.

```
var text = document.getElementById('myText');
var myData;
var postData = window.localStorage.getItem("save");
var reset = text.innerHTML;
// if no data
if (postData == null || postData == '') {
    myData = text.innerHTML;
    // store default value
    window.localStorage.setItem("save", myData);
    // make it placeholder style
    text.classList.remove('changed');
} else {
    // if there is a value post it
    text.innerHTML = postData;
    // make dark text
    text.classList.add('changed');
}

function saveChanges() {
    // store the current value
    myData = text.innerHTML;
    // local store the value
    window.localStorage.setItem("save", myData);
    text.classList.add('changed');
}

function clearStorage() {
    text.classList.remove('changed');
    // clear storage
    window.localStorage.clear("save");
    // return to default text
    text.innerHTML = reset;
}
```

Update: I just found this code to model mine after, but I can't seem to implement it. When I do, I am no longer able to add tasks.

```
var appx = angular.module('mainApp',[]);

appx.controller('app',function($scope) {
    $scope.tasks = [];
    var taskData = localStorage['tasksList'];
    if(taskData !== undefined){
        $scope.tasks = JSON.parse(taskData);
    }
    $scope.searchEnter = function(event) {
        //console.log(event.keyCode); 
        if(event.which==13 && $scope.task!=''){
            $scope.addTask();
        }
    };
    $scope.addTask=function(event){
        $scope.tasks.push({'taskmsg':$scope.task, 'status':false});
        //console.log($scope.task);
        $scope.task='';
        localStorage['tasksList']=JSON.stringify($scope.tasks);
    };
    $scope.editContent=function(event,mm){
        console.log(mm);
        for(i=0;i<$scope.tasks.length;i++){
            if($scope.tasks[i].taskmsg==mm){
                console.log(i);
                $scope.tasks[i].taskmsg=event.target.innerText;
            }
        }
        event.target.contentEditable = event.target.contentEditable == "false" ? "true" : "false";
        localStorage['tasksList']=JSON.stringify($scope.tasks);
        //event.target.contentEditable = event.target.contentEditable == "false" ? "true" : "false";
    };
    $scope.enter=function(event,msg){
        if(event.which==13 && msg!=''){
        //console.log('asd');
        $scope.editContent(msg);
        }
        ///console.log('wq');
    }
    $scope.delfield=function(mm){
        console.log("2");
        for(i=0;i<$scope.tasks.length;i++){
            if($scope.tasks[i].taskmsg==mm){
                console.log(mm);
                console.log(localStorage['tasksList']);
                $scope.tasks.splice(i,1);
                localStorage['tasksList']=JSON.stringify($scope.tasks);
            }
        }
    }
    $scope.sort=function(){
        console.log("sort");
        
    }
});
```

Comment: my wild guess is that you need an directive for the contenteditable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28583651/contenteditable-with-ng-model-doesnt-work, then you can use ng-model and ng-change on the contenteditable element!

Comment: @BettySt Thank you. I'll check that out!

Comment: If the issue is that localStorage['tasksList']=JSON.stringify($scope.tasks); line doesn't save the value in localstorage, it is because some line before didn't work. Do all console.log()s work as expected?

Comment: @Vega Thank you for your response. There are no errors in the console.

Comment: But do console.log()s that you have already put in your code print the expected values? All of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues with the code example that is provided, I am not able to fix all the logical errors as I am not completely aware about the functionality, but I did change few things and now editing `contentEditable` items are getting updated correctly.

Now coming to the changes I made, there were couple which are crucial:

1. Adding blur event listener on `p` element

   ```
   <p id="myText" contentEditable class="changed" ng-on-blur="contentEdit($event, task)">
       {{ task.text }}
   </p>
   ```
2. Updating `contentEdit` method as it had lots of code that I think is unnecessary, as we can already get reference to `task` and `$watch` is already doing heavy lifting of monitoring change and saving to local storage

   ```
   $scope.contentEdit = function (event, task) {
       const newText = event.target.innerText;
       if (newText && task) {
           task.text = newText;
           console.log(event.target.innerText);
       }
   }
   ```

Also, I am not sure what exact purpose of attached JS file was, but if you can explain bit further I can take a look. Finally, take a look at updated code, I have updated SCSS to CSS but I haven't changed anything:

```js
var app = angular.module("TodoApp", ["LocalStorageModule"]);

app.controller("TodoController", function($scope, localStorageService) {
  if (!localStorageService.get("taskListActive")) {
    $scope.tasksActive = [{
        text: "Do me next",
        priority: 1,
        complete: false
      },
      {
        text: "I'm not important",
        priority: 0,
        complete: false
      }
    ];
  } else {
    $scope.tasksActive = localStorageService.get("taskListActive");
  }

  if (!localStorageService.get("taskListComplete")) {
    $scope.tasksComplete = [{
      text: "I'm already done",
      priority: 0,
      complete: true
    }];
  } else {
    $scope.tasksComplete = localStorageService.get("taskListComplete");
  }

  $scope.totalTasks = function() {
    console.log($scope.tasksComplete.length);
    return $scope.tasksActive.length + $scope.tasksComplete.length;
  };

  $scope.totalRemaining = function() {
    return $scope.tasksActive.length;
  };

  $scope.totalComplete = function() {
    return $scope.tasksActive.length;
  };

  $scope.todoAdd = function() {
    if ($scope.taskInput.name) {
      $scope.tasksActive.unshift({
        text: $scope.taskInput.name,
        priority: $scope.taskInput.priority || 0,
        complete: false
      });
      $scope.taskInput.name = "";
      $scope.taskInput.priority = 0;
    }
  };

  $scope.togglePriority = function(task) {
    if (task.priority === 0) {
      task.priority = 1;
      console.log("a");
    } else {
      task.priority = 0;
    }
  };

  $scope.completeTask = function(task) {
    //var task = $scope.tasksActive[index];
    task.complete = true;
    task.priority = 0;
    $scope.tasksActive.splice($scope.tasksActive.indexOf(task), 1);
    $scope.tasksComplete.unshift(task);
  };

  $scope.uncompleteTask = function(task) {
    task.complete = false;
    $scope.tasksComplete.splice($scope.tasksComplete.indexOf(task), 1);
    $scope.tasksActive.unshift(task);
  };

  $scope.deleteTask = function(task, list) {
    if (list == "active") {
      $scope.tasksActive.splice($scope.tasksActive.indexOf(task), 1);
    } else {
      $scope.tasksComplete.splice($scope.tasksComplete.indexOf(task), 1);
    }
  };

  $scope.clearCompleted = function() {
    var deleteArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tasksComplete.length; i++) deleteArr.push(i);
    for (var i = 0; i < deleteArr.length; i++) {
      var task = i;
      $scope.tasksComplete.splice($scope.tasksComplete.indexOf(task) - 1, 1);
    }
  };

  $scope.$watch(
    "tasksActive",
    function(newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log("tasksActive");
      if (newVal !== null && angular.isDefined(newVal) && newVal !== oldVal) {
        localStorageService.add("taskListActive", angular.toJson(newVal));
      }
    },
    true
  );

  $scope.$watch(
    "tasksComplete",
    function(newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log("tasksComplete");
      if (newVal !== null && angular.isDefined(newVal) && newVal !== oldVal) {
        localStorageService.add("taskListComplete", angular.toJson(newVal));
      }
    },
    true
  );

  $scope.contentEdit = function(event, task) {
    const newText = event.target.innerText;
    if (newText && task) {
      task.text = newText;
      console.log(event.target.innerText);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.max-width {
  max-width: 600px;
}

.centered {
  margin: auto;
}

.text-center-h {
  text-align: center;
}

.text-left {
  text-align: left;
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}

.list-no-style {
  list-style: none outside none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  color: #333;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 10px;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #bbdefb 0%, #311b92 100%);
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.block {
  font-size: 0;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.block>* {
  font-size: medium;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.block-justify {
  text-align: justify;
}

.block-justify:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.block-justify>* {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.block-table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.block-table>* {
  display: table-cell;
}

.fa {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #bbb;
  padding: 0 6px;
  transition: color 0.2s ease;
}

.fa.-clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}

button.-add,
.btn.-add {
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 0 0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #0eb2f0;
  background: #56c9f5;
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
}

button.-add:hover,
.btn.-add:hover {
  background: #6ed1f6;
}

button.-add:active,
.btn.-add:active {
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}

button.-clear,
.btn.-clear {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  background: none;
  color: #bbb;
}

button.-clear:hover,
.btn.-clear:hover {
  color: tomato;
}

.task-list._wrap {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  box-shadow: 18px 18px 0 0 #56c9f5;
}

.task-list._wrap h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
}

.totals._wrap,
.search {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.totals._wrap {
  font-size: 0;
}

.totals._grand-total,
.totals._detail {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: medium;
}

.totals._grand-total {
  text-align: center;
  height: 90px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  background: #64b5f6;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.totals._grand-total span {
  display: block;
}

.totals._total-number {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.totals._detail p {
  height: 60px;
  padding: 3px 6px;
}

.search._wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.search .fa {
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.search input.-text {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.add-form._wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #694ede;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 #694ede;
}

.add-form input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
}

.add-form._buttons {
  position: absolute;
  right: 12px;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 180px;
  font-size: 0;
}

.add-form._checkbox-wrap,
.add-form._submit-button {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: medium;
  height: 100%;
}

.add-form._checkbox {
  padding: 0 12px;
}

.add-form._checkbox input {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.add-form._checkbox .fa:hover {
  color: #7b7b7b;
}

.add-form._checkbox input:checked+.fa {
  color: tomato;
}

.add-form._submit-button {
  height: 42px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

input.-text {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  height: 46px;
}

input.-add-task {
  border: none;
  border: 2px solid #64b5f6;
}

input.-search {
  border: 2px solid #64b5f6;
}

.task._item {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.task._item a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.task.-done-false {
  color: #56c9f5;
}

.task.-done-false p,
.task.-done-false a {
  color: #333;
}

.task.-done-true {
  color: #d5d5d5;
}

.task.-done-true p,
.task.-done-true a {
  color: #bbb;
}

.task._task-left,
.task._task-right {
  height: 66px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.task._task-left {
  width: calc(100% - 180px);
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.task._task-right {
  width: 180px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.task._task-right .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.task._task-right .btn.-priority:hover .fa {
  color: #7b7b7b;
}

.task._task-right .btn.-complete:hover .fa,
.task._task-right .btn.-re-open:hover .fa {
  color: #0eb2f0;
}

.task._task-right .btn.-clear:hover .fa {
  color: tomato;
}

.task.-task-priority-high ._task-left {
  padding-left: 28px;
  position: relative;
}

.task.-task-priority-high ._task-left:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 6px;
  top: 12px;
  bottom: 12px;
  left: 12px;
  background: tomato;
}

.task.-task-priority-high .btn.-priority .fa {
  color: tomato;
}

p {
  margin: 1em;
  color: #777;
}

p.changed {
  color: black;
}

button {
  margin: 0 1em;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  padding: 4px 10px 4px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  *margin-left: 0.3em;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
  *line-height: 20px;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  *background-color: #e6e6e6;
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#fff), to(#e6e6e6));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #e6e6e6);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  *border: 0;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
  border-bottom-color: #b3b3b3;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e6e6e6', GradientType=0);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
  *zoom: 1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  *background-color: #d9d9d9;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  *background-color: #d9d9d9;
  background-position: 0 -15px;
  -webkit-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
  -moz-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
  -ms-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
  -o-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
  transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
}

.btn:active {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  *background-color: #d9d9d9;
  background-color: #ccc \9;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  background-color: #d9d9d9 \9;
  background-image: none;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.btn:first-child {
  *margin-left: 0;
}

.btn:focus {
  outline: thin dotted #333;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}

.btn.active {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  *background-color: #d9d9d9;
  background-color: #ccc \9;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  background-color: #d9d9d9 \9;
  background-image: none;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.btn.disabled {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  *background-color: #d9d9d9;
}

.btn[disabled] {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  *background-color: #d9d9d9;
}

.btn-primary {
  background-color: #0074cc;
  *background-color: #05c;
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #08c, #05c);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#08c), to(#05c));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #08c, #05c);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #08c, #05c);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #08c, #05c);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #08c, #05c);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-color: #05c #05c #003580;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0088cc', endColorstr='#0055cc', GradientType=0);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.btn-primary:hover {
  background-color: #05c;
  *background-color: #004ab3;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.btn-primary:active {
  background-color: #05c;
  *background-color: #004ab3;
  background-color: #004099 \9;
}

.btn-primary.active {
  background-color: #05c;
  *background-color: #004ab3;
  background-color: #004099 \9;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

.btn-primary.disabled {
  background-color: #05c;
  *background-color: #004ab3;
}

.btn-primary[disabled] {
  background-color: #05c;
  *background-color: #004ab3;
}

.btn-warning {
  background-color: #faa732;
  *background-color: #f89406;
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450, #f89406);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#fbb450), to(#f89406));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450, #f89406);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450, #f89406);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450, #f89406);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fbb450, #f89406);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-color: #f89406 #f89406 #ad6704;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fbb450', endColorstr='#f89406', GradientType=0);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.btn-warning:hover {
  background-color: #f89406;
  *background-color: #df8505;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.btn-warning:active {
  background-color: #f89406;
  *background-color: #df8505;
  background-color: #c67605 \9;
}

.btn-warning.active {
  background-color: #f89406;
  *background-color: #df8505;
  background-color: #c67605 \9;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

.btn-warning.disabled {
  background-color: #f89406;
  *background-color: #df8505;
}

.btn-warning[disabled] {
  background-color: #f89406;
  *background-color: #df8505;
}

.btn-danger {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.btn-danger:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.btn-success {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.btn-success:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.btn-info {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.btn-info:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.btn-inverse {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.btn-inverse:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.btn-danger.active {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

.btn-success.active {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

.btn-info.active {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

.btn-inverse.active {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.8.0/angular.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/131045/ngLocalStorage.js">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</link>
<div ng-app="TodoApp" ng-controller="TodoController" class="task-list _wrap centered max-width text-center-h">
  <h1>Notes:</h1>
  <div class="block-justify" style="position: relative; left: -153px; top: -14px;">
    <div class="totals _wrap text-left">
      <div class="totals _detail">


      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="search _wrap text-right">
      <input class="input -text -search" type="text" placeholder="Search tasks" ng-model="taskSearch.name" />
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <form class="add-form _wrap block text-left">
    <input class="input -text -add-task" type="text" placeholder="Add a new task" ng-model="taskInput.name" ng-model-instant />
    <div class="add-form _buttons text-right">
      <p>Priority</p>
      <div class="add-form _checkbox-wrap">
        <label class="add-form _checkbox"><input class="input -checkbox" type="checkbox" name="priority"
                                ng-model="taskInput.priority" ng-init="checked=false" parse-int ng-true-value="1"
                                ng-false-value="0"><i class="fa fa-exclamation -clickable"></i></label>
      </div>
      <button class="add-form _submit-button btn -add" ng-click="todoAdd()">Add</button>
    </div>
  </form>

  <ul class="list-no-style text-left">
    <li ng-repeat="task in tasksActive | filter:taskSearch.name | orderBy:'-priority'" class="task _item -done-{{ task.complete }} -task-priority-{{ task.priority==true ? 'high' : 'low' }} block-table">
      <div class="task _task-left" ;>
        <p id="myText" contentEditable class="changed" ng-on-blur="contentEdit($event, task)">
          {{ task.text }}
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="task _task-right text-right">
        <a href ng-click="togglePriority(task)" class="btn -task-action -priority" title="Change priority"><i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i></a>
        <a href ng-click="completeTask(task)" class="btn -task-action -complete" title="Complete"><i
                                class="fa fa-check"></i></a>
        <a href ng-click="deleteTask(task,'active')" class="btn -clear" title="Delete"><i
                                class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="task in tasksComplete | filter:taskSearch.name" class="task _item -done-{{ task.complete }} block">
      <p class="task _task-left">{{ task.text }}</p>
      <div class="task _task-right text-right">
        <a href ng-click="uncompleteTask(task)" class="btn -task-action -re-open" title="Re-open"><i
                                class="fa fa-undo"></i></a>
        <a href ng-click="deleteTask(task,'complete')" class="btn -clear" title="Delete"><i
                                class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <form class="text-right">
    <button class="btn -clear" ng-show="tasksComplete.length" ng-click="clearCompleted()">Delete all
                    completed</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I have one more question if you don't mind. This works very well, but with one hitch. The following video is an illustration of it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yN2oUntxAkPdkXNWCjiWC1XFcNqa_O1j/view. The text remains, but the tabs I make don't.

Comment: @zbush548 you can do two things to check, 1. see the local storage and see if they are stored, 2. check the content of `p` tag. Most likely it is because `p` doesn't support tabs, you will need to convert them somehow!

Comment: @DiepnShah Thank you. That helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your problem is due to next reason but Local Storage only allows strings.

Stringify your data should work.

```
JSON.stringify(data.toString())
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I actually don't believe that to be the issue, seeing as the original that does not involve contenteditable works alone without the data being stringified.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

```
var app = angular.module('TodoApp', ["LocalStorageModule"]);

app.controller('TodoController', function($scope, localStorageService) {
  
  if (!localStorageService.get("taskListActive")) {
    $scope.tasksActive = [
      {
        text: "Do me next",
        priority: 1,
        complete: false
      },
      {
        text: "I'm not important",
        priority: 0,
        complete: false
      }
    ];
    
  } else {
    $scope.tasksActive = localStorageService.get("taskListActive");
  }
  
  if (!localStorageService.get("taskListComplete")) {
    $scope.tasksComplete = [
      {
        text: "I'm already done",
        priority: 0,
        complete: true
      }
    ];
  } else {
    $scope.tasksComplete = localStorageService.get("taskListComplete");
  }
  
  $scope.totalTasks = function() {
    console.log($scope.tasksComplete.length)
    return $scope.tasksActive.length + $scope.tasksComplete.length;
  }
  
  $scope.totalRemaining = function() {
    return $scope.tasksActive.length;
  };
  
  $scope.totalComplete = function() {
    return $scope.tasksActive.length;
  };
  
  $scope.todoAdd = function() {
    if ($scope.taskInput.name) {
      $scope.tasksActive.unshift({ text:$scope.taskInput.name, priority:$scope.taskInput.priority || 0, complete:false});
      $scope.taskInput.name = '';
      $scope.taskInput.priority = 0;
    }
  };
  
  $scope.togglePriority = function(task) {
    if( task.priority === 0 ) {
      task.priority = 1;
      console.log('a')
    } else {
      task.priority = 0;
    }
  };
  
  $scope.completeTask = function(task) {
    //var task = $scope.tasksActive[index];
    task.complete = true;
    task.priority = 0;
    $scope.tasksActive.splice($scope.tasksActive.indexOf(task), 1);
    $scope.tasksComplete.unshift(task);
  };
  
  $scope.uncompleteTask = function(task) {
    task.complete = false;
    $scope.tasksComplete.splice($scope.tasksComplete.indexOf(task), 1);
    $scope.tasksActive.unshift(task);
  };
  
  $scope.deleteTask = function(task,list) {
    if( list == "active" ) {
      $scope.tasksActive.splice($scope.tasksActive.indexOf(task), 1);
    } else {
      $scope.tasksComplete.splice($scope.tasksComplete.indexOf(task), 1);
    }
    
  };
   
  $scope.clearCompleted = function () {
      var deleteArr= [];
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tasksComplete.length; i++) deleteArr.push(i);
      for (var i = 0; i < deleteArr.length; i++) {
        var task = i;
        $scope.tasksComplete.splice($scope.tasksComplete.indexOf(task) - 1, 1);
      }
  };

  $scope.$watch("tasksActive",function  (newVal,oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== null && angular.isDefined(newVal) && newVal!==oldVal) {
            localStorageService.add("taskListActive",angular.toJson(newVal));
        }
    },true);
  
  $scope.$watch("tasksComplete",function  (newVal,oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== null && angular.isDefined(newVal) && newVal!==oldVal) {
            localStorageService.add("taskListComplete",angular.toJson(newVal));
        }
    },true);
  
});




const editables = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable]");

// save edits
editables.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("blur", () => {
    localStorage.setItem("dataStorage-" + el.id, el.innerHTML);
  })
});

// once on load
for (var key in localStorage) {
  if (key.includes("dataStorage-")) {
    const id = key.replace("dataStorage-","");
    document.querySelector("#" + id).innerHTML = localStorage.getItem(key);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still face the same issue. It does not save.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure then.